# How to Change X-Axis Label in ChromoMap?

Tags: r, annotations, htmlwidgets, genome

I am new to R and I have been using [chromoMap](https://lakshay-anand.github.io/chromoMap/) library in R to visualize annotation plots and visualizing the feature-associated data. It's a great library and produces great charts. However, I was not able to find any option for changing the x-axis label from **length (bp)** to anything else. Because of this, I am not able to use any of the produced charts. It sounds like a small issue, but it totally affects the usability of this great package. I followed this tutorial [link](https://lakshay-anand.github.io/chromoMap/docs.html) and produced the below chart. In my chart and all the samples, the x-axis label is fixed and this is my problem and I am looking for a way to just change it.

```
library(chromoMap)
chr_file_1 = "chr_file_without_centromere.txt"
anno_file_1 = "annotation_pos.txt"
chromoMap(chr_file_1,anno_file_1)
```

[image]

I am wondering if anybody has the same experience ?? This package produces output as a htmlwidget object and therefore I could not change the x-axis lable. Is there any way to modify a htmlwidget object? or Any way to change this **bp** to something else??

Comment: It's not going to be easy, since the x-axis label is [hard-coded in the underlying Javascript](https://github.com/cran/chromoMap/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/lib/chromoMap-3.0/chromoMap-3.0.js).

Comment: @neilfws thank you for your comments. If I change the javascript file and compile it again, it would work?

Comment: I would think you would have to download the package as a zip file, edit the .js file and then install from the zip. Another option might be to locate and edit the .js file after installation.

Comment: Just to add: of course, you would need to re-edit the .js file if the package is ever updated.